# I cannot remember my profile log in details on the US Visa website

Tags: visas, applications

I last applied for a US Visa in 2013. Now that I want to apply again, I am not able to remember the details of the profile I created before. can I create another profile as a new user?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the forgot option, if you still have access to the email id with which you created the CGI profile. Otherwise when you create a new profile, with same passport, it will show you that your personal details exist, you can contact us traveldocs and merge the account.

If you have a new passport, you can go ahead and create a new profile.